# Media queries are working on Inspector but not on live site

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

Custom css (media queries) work for WordPress and inspector but not on live site.

I added the `meta viewport` tag to the HTML but still it's not working.

```
/* Media Queries */

/* small phones */

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #intro {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 85%;
  }
  .logo-image {
    position: relative;
  }
  .logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  main {
    width: 85%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .card {
    width: 85%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer #left-footer {
    flex: 1;
    border-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  footer #right-footer {
    background: #eee;
    color: black;
  }
  footer #right-footer a {
    color: black;
  }
  footer #social-media-footer ul li:hover a .fa-instagram {
    color: purple;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: flex;
  }
  #slideout-menu {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #searchbox {
    display: none;
  }
  #blogpost {
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  .comment-form {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  #slideout-menu {
    width: 65%;
  }
  #logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  #intro {
    width: 95%;
    height: 120vw;
  }
  #intro .logo-image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    max-height: 750px;
    position: relative;
    right: 18px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .card {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  .card .card-description {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@media (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  #nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #slideout-menu {
    width: 65%;
  }
  #logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  #intro {
    width: auto;
    height: 120vw;
  }
  #intro .logo-image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 750px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  main {
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .card {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  .card .card-description {
    width: 100%
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: flex;
  }
  #slideout-menu {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #searchbox {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  #comments-section {
    width: 140%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
  .logo-image {
    display: flex;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .card {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Tablet */

@media screen and (min-width: 668px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    font-size: 2vw;
  }
  #logo-img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    max-height: 750px;
  }
  #intro {
    width: auto;
    height: 100vw;
  }
  #intro .logo-image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
  }
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card,
  .card .Card Image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer #left-footer {
    flex: 1;
    border-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  footer #right-footer {
    background: #eee;
    color: black;
  }
  footer #right-footer a {
    color: black;
  }
  footer #social-media-footer ul li:hover a .fa-instagram {
    color: purple;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  #searchbox {
    display: ;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 150px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #logo-img {
    left: 30px
  }
  .logo-image {
    display: flex;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .card {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  #logo-img {
    left: 30px
  }
  .logo-image {
    display: flex;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
  }
  .card {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .card .card-image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #logo-img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 680px;
    max-height: 750px;
  }
  #intro {
    width: auto;
    height: 100vw;
  }
  #intro .logo-image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 2500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    top: -200px;
  }
  main {
    width: 95%;
  }
  section {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card,
  .card .Card Image img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  footer #left-footer {
    flex: 1;
    border-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  footer #right-footer {
    background: #eee;
    color: black;
  }
  footer #right-footer a {
    color: black;
  }
  footer #social-media-footer ul li:hover a .fa-instagram {
    color: purple;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }
  #searchbox {
    display: ;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 200px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #logo-img {
    left: 30px
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML

">
                            /img/fuchsifuchs.png" alt="fuchsifuchs.png"  class="fuchs-intro"/>
                         
                       


        

        
            ">
                Gedichte
            

                


             'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                    );

                    $Gedichteposts = new WP_QUERY($args);

                    while($Gedichteposts->have_posts()) {
                    $Gedichteposts->the_post();

            ?>
                    
                        
                            ">
                                "
                                alt="Card Image">
                                
                    

                    
                        ">

" class="btn-readmore"> weiter erkunden

```
        </section>

    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/projects'); ?>">
    <h2 class="section-heading"> Kurzgeschichten</h2>

    <section>
    <?php 

        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        );

        $project = new WP_QUERY($args);

        while($project->have_posts()) {
        $project->the_post();


        ?>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href=" <?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>"
                    alt="Card Image">
                </a>    
        </div>

        <div class="card-description">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </a>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?>
            </p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore"> weiter erkunden</a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <?php } 
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>

        </section>

    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/about'); ?>">
    <h2 class="section-heading"> Das bin ich</h2>

    <section id="section-source">
        <p>
        Wenn Ihr mehr über mich und meine Geschichte erfahren wollt, schaut gerne hier rein. Ich erzähle euch, wie es zu diesem Blog gekommen ist und warum ihr rein schauen solltet.
        </p>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/fabiancheves8/" class="btn-readmore">Instagram Profil</a>
    </section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your HTML? How would anyone be able to test this without that? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You also have an extra closing bracket at the very end.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for your help, I will add my Html quickly. sorry for the inconvienience

Comment: Thanks for posting more information. Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: alright, sorry again! I hope that it is the rendered code that im going to post, please correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 0):

A common issue I encounter when trying to write css from the WordPress admin panel is that my css is being overwritten. To solve this, you can try to match the specificity of the already existent css or if you are brave just add "!important" before the ";" of every rule.

Would recommend looking into specificity first, though.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer - since we do not have enough information to even come close to providing an answer. I would remove this (before it gets down voted) and add this as a comment.

Comment: @disinfor I am sorry if I did not provide the right information.. I am really a beginner.. What would you need to provide an answer? I know you might not have the time to answer this but I would still appreciate any help I can get